# Smart conversion of double to single quotes in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

## Problem

In a source file, I have a large number of strings. Some with interpolation, some with special symbols and some with neither.

I am trying to work out if I can replace the simple strings' double quotes with single quotes whilst leaving double quotes for the interpolated and special symbol strings. I would then run this conversion on one or more source code files.

I imagine there is probably a nice regex for this, but I can't quite formulate it.

## Example - Code

Imagine the following code:

```
def myfunc(var, var2 = "abc")
  s = "something"
  puts "a simple string"
  puts "string with a single ' quote"
  puts "string with a newline \n"  
  puts "my #{var}"
end
```

## Example - Result

I would like to turn it into this:

```
def myfunc(var, var2 = 'abc')
  s = 'something'
  puts 'a simple string'
  puts "string with a single ' quote"
  puts "string with a newline \n"  
  puts "my #{var}"
end
```

If anyone has any ideas I'd be very grateful!

Comment: You want to make this change in the actual source file, right?

Comment: Yes, ideally I would run this over one or multiple files. Will update question to reflect.

Comment: why are you so fixed on regexen?

Comment: I'm not particularly. Anything which gets the job done would work, it's a one off conversion. Regexes just seemed like they might be what people would recommend anyway?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this cannot be done using Regexs. This would require a full-fledged parser like stdlib's Ripper (http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/ripper/rdoc/Ripper.html).

Comment: Why exactly would you want to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you can read your string from your file by yourself into an array `strings`:

```
strings = [ "\"a simple string\"",
            "\"string with a single ' quote\"",
            "\"string with a newline \n\""
            "\"my \#{var}\"" ]
```

then we would `eval` them to see how they behave:

```
$SAFE = 4
single_quoted_when_possible = strings.map { |double_quoted|
  begin
    string = eval( double_quoted ) # this string, as Ruby sees it
    raise unless string.is_a? String
    raise unless '"' + string + '"' == double_quoted
  rescue
    raise "Array element is not a string!"
  end
  begin  
    raise unless eval( "'#{string}'" ) == string
    "'#{string}'"
  rescue
    double_quoted
  end
}
```

And that SAFE level 4 is just woodoo, just an acknowledgement from me that we are doing something dangerous. I do not know to what extent it actually protects against all dangers.

In your particular case, you can create a Regexp heuristic, relying on hope that nobody will write "evil" strings in your code, such as `/= *(".+") *$/` or `/\w+ *\(* *(".+") *\)* *$/`. That heuristic would extract some string suspects, to which you could further apply the method I wrote higher above. But I would still have human look at each replacement, and run tests on the resulting code afterwards.

Comment: Thanks, but how would this apply in place?

Comment: @PeterHamilton: `"\"'#{'"\""#{"'"'"}'\"\"'}"'"'`. Or check http://mamememo.blogspot.com. Are you getting your problem?

Comment: How does this deal with `"#{method_which_isnt_visible_from_converter_context(args)}"` ?

Comment: Let me make clear that my solution is just a kluge. My heuristic is a kluge, too. Anything short of usin Ripper, as Dogbert suggested, will have problems. You could eg. instance eval in an object with #method_missing defined to bypass the problem you just mentioned, but there would be other problems. Feel free to visit http://www.rubyinside.com/using-ripper-to-see-how-ruby-is-parsing-your-code-5270.html and analyze the sexps resulting from running `Ripper.sexp contents_of_your_source_file`, searching for `:string_literal` and `:string_content` fields to see what's going on.

Comment: And if anyone actually writes code to modify all string literals in a Ruby source code, don't forget to publish it, that's big piece of functionality that many would appreciate and few have time to implement. Do not expect to get perfectly working orignal solution here at SO.

Comment: I don't expect perfect code! This is all really helpful. I was also curious about going the other way, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16540932/smart-conversion-of-single-to-double-quotes-in-ruby/16543278?noredirect=1#16543278

That's much easier though since single quotes don't really contain any voodoo.