# Smart conversion of single to double quotes in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

## Problem

In a source file, I have a large number of strings.ome with interpolation, some with special symbols and some with neither.

I am trying to work out if I can replace the single quotes with double quotes whilst converting escaped single quote characters. I would then run this conversion on one or more source code files.

## Example - Code

Imagine the following code:

```
def myfunc(var, var2 = 'abc')
  s = 'something'
  puts 'a simple string'
  puts 'string with an escaped quote \' in it'
  x = "nasty #{interpolated}" + s + ' and single quote combo'
  puts "my #{var}"
end
```

## Example - Result

I would like to turn it into this:

```
def myfunc(var, var2 = "abc")
  s = "something"
  puts "a simple string"
  puts "string with an escaped quote ' in it"
  x = "nasty #{interpolated}" + s + " and single quote combo"
  puts "my #{var}"
end
```

If anyone has any ideas I'd be very grateful!

Comment: can you post what have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want negative look behind `(?<!)` operator:

**REGEX**

```
 (?<!\)'
```

**DEMO**

http://regex101.com/r/rN5eE6

**EXPLANATION**

- You want to replace any single quote not preceded by a backslash.
- Don't forget to do a find and replace of all `\'` with `'`

**THERE IS MORE**

For this use case, even if it's a simple use case, a ruby parser would perform better.

Comment: One thing I found was single quotes within double quotes were'nt caught. Not in my original example. http://regex101.com/r/uS6sS7

Comment: With the issue you have pointed out, you have reached the *limit* of the regular expressions. A ruby parser is far more suited for solving this problem.

Answer (score 2):

As Peter Hamilton pointed out, although replacing single quoted strings with double quoted equivalents might seem as an easy task at first, even that cannot be done easily, if at all, with regexen, mainly thanks to the possibility of single quotes in the "wrong places", such as within double-quoted strings, `%q` literal string constructs, heredocs, comments...

```
x = 'puts "foo"'
y = %/puts 'foo'/ # TODO: Replace "x = %/puts 'foo'/" with "x = %#puts 'bar'#"
```

But the correct solution, in this case, is much easier than the other way around (double quoted to single quoted), and actually partially attainable:

```
require 'ripper'
require 'sorcerer' # gem install sorcerer if necessary
my_source = <<-source
  x = 'puts "foo"'
  y = "puts 'bar'"
source
sexp = Ripper::SexpBuilder.new( my_source ).parse
double_quoted_source = Sorcerer.source sexp
#=> "x = \"puts \"foo\"\"; y = \"puts 'bar'\""
```

The reason why I say "partially attainable" is because, as you can see by yourself,

```
puts double_quoted_source
#=> x = "puts "foo""; y = "puts 'bar'"
```

Sorcerer forgets to escape double quotes inside formerly single-quoted string. Feel free [to submit a patch
to sorcerer's author Jim Weirich](https://github.com/jimweirich/sorcerer) that would fix the problem.